# Gaussian to Uniform distribution conversion has errors at the edges of Uniform distribution

Tags: python, distribution, gaussian, cdf, uniform-distribution

I have a number of samples generated from a Gaussian distribution and I want to convert them so they have a uniform distribution. I follow these steps:

1- Standardize the Gaussian distribution so it has mean of 0 and std of 1.

2- Use the CDF of this standardized Gaussian distribution to get Uniform distribution.

I approximate the CDF using the method explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). However the end result is not uniform. It looks like uniform in the middle but at the edges (near 0 and 1) there are errors.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ================= Parameers ===================

mu = 5.0
sig = 2.0
data_cnt = 10**6
bin_cnt = 10**3


# ================ Functions ===================

# Estimates gaussian distribution parameters from data using ML
def gaussian_estimation(vector):
    mu = np.mean(vector)
    sig = np.std(vector)

    return (mu,sig)

# Adjusts the data so it forms a gaussian with mean of 0 and std of 1
def gaussian_normalization(vector, char = None):

    if char is None:
        mu , sig = gaussian_estimation(vector)
    else:
        mu = char[2]
        sig = char[3]

    normalized = (vector-mu)/np.sqrt(sig)

    return normalized

# Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function
def CDF(x, max_i = 100):
    sum = x
    value = x
    for i in np.arange(max_i)+1:
        value = value*x*x/(2.0*i+1)
        sum = sum + value

    return 0.5 + (sum/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-1*(x*x)/2)

def gaussian_to_uniform(vector, if_normal = False):

    if (if_normal == False):
        vector = gaussian_normalization(vector)

    uni = np.apply_along_axis(CDF, 0, vector)

    return uni


# ========== Step1: Data Generation ============

data = np.random.normal(mu, sig, data_cnt)
plt.hist(data,bin_cnt)


# ========= Step2: Data Normalization ==========

data2 = gaussian_normalization(data)
plt.hist(data2,bin_cnt)


# ======== Step3: Data Uniformization ==========

data3 = gaussian_to_uniform(data2, if_normal = True)
plt.hist(data3,bin_cnt)
```

So can anyone help me with this issue? Maybe the approximation method is not so accurate?

Comment: I think I see the problem but I'm not sure.  If the blue curve is your original gaussian and the orange curve is your normalized gaussian, the ratio of their widths should be 2:1.  It's not - the orange curve is too wide.  When you normalize the width in the function `gaussian_normalization`, you divide the width by the square root of the ratio of the sigmas.  I don't think there should be a `sqrt` in there.  So the next step, mapping to a uniform distribution, doesn't work because the normalized gaussian distribution is too wide.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Oh yes you are right. Originally I used variance and when I switched to std I forgot to remove the sqrt function. It now works fine and I get a nice uniform distribution. Thank you very much.